# Redux-form async validation on optional field

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Issue:

If I don't pass a promise to from asyncValidate function it fails with `asyncValidation.js:8 Uncaught Error: asyncValidate function passed to reduxForm must return a promise` also how can I access props passed to component in `asyncValidat` function
[failed validation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGabB.png).

My case:

The form has options to select a fixed URL and then if you want to enter custom URL you can select the custom checkbox and enter URL in textfield. I need to validate entered custom URL.

This field only has a value when user chooses to enter the Custom URL. It works fine when you send a value in my custom URL text field. The submission fails with an above-mentioned error when I don't send a value to the field

Code for async validator:

```
const asyncValidate = values => {
  const { custom_url } = values;
  const noFeedError = { custom_url: "No feeds found" };
  const fetchFailedError = { custom_url: "Fetch failed, try again" };

  if (custom_url && custom_url !== "") {
    return fetchOnlineFeeds(custom_url) //fetches if URL is valid fails with 503 
      .then(feedResult => {
        if (feedResult.error) {
          throw noFeedError;
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        throw fetchFailedError;
      });
  }
};
```

searched and found:

- https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/1166
- https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/1297

but seems nothing is working and  if we have to return a promise in else what is the best way

Comment: also seems you have a lonely }; at the end, check that that opens somewhere

Comment: was formatting issue updated code block, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem I think is that you are returning undefined outside the if, try to refactor to return a promise either way

just return `Promise.resolve()` after your if, you could I guess also instead `return new Promise()`

```
const asyncValidate = values => {
  const { custom_url } = values;
  const noFeedError = { custom_url: "No feeds found" };
  const fetchFailedError = { custom_url: "Fetch failed, try again" };

  if (custom_url && custom_url !== "") {
    return fetchOnlineFeeds(custom_url) //fetches if URL is valid fails with 503 
      .then(feedResult => {
        if (feedResult.error) {
          throw noFeedError;
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        throw fetchFailedError;
      });
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

Comment: best way seems to be Promise.resolve() , need more context but if you need that file to return a promise you cant make it return a promise conditionally and then for the program consumed if no condition is met the value of the return is undefined, so probably that breaks whatever is breaking there

Comment: @SantiagoRebella hey can you also answer the second part of question so that i can approve you answer. How can i access the props in asyncValidate function. need to add few checks based on props, before validating URL

Comment: @Ukie Docs are your friend. https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-asyncvalidate-values-object-dispatch-function-props-object-blurredfield-string-gt-promise-lt-undefined-errors-object-gt-code-optional- The `asyncValidate` function has a signature `(values, dispatch, props, burredField)`. Please try to limit SO issues to a single specific issue and not ask multiple questions.

Comment: DrewReese Thanks , i'll try and limit to single question in future.

@SantiagoRebella Thanks for help it worked